# Are there any Linux Server to Linux Client XenApp equivalents available?

Tags: linux, remote, desktop, xenapp

I am a college student with a predominantly business background looking into a business concept, which centers around remote access of Linux applications. I have experience with Citrix XenApp through work and I've trying to find a similar system for the Linux platform without much luck. Open source is preferable, as I will need to create a custom client and I would prefer to dedicate my budget entirely into coding and infrastructure setup.

My question is: Are there any Linux Server to Linux Client XenApp equivalents available?

Answer (score 4):

[X Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) has existed for over 20 years.

The concept of remote logins (serial cable leading back to the server, rsh, telnet, ssh) and running your CPU-heavy apps on a server that is centrally managed by the IT department has existed since before Linux was even a gleam in Linus' eye (if we say that idea originated at the epoch it's over 30 years old).

Figuring out how you bill for usage is an exercise for the business major (flat monthly fees are probably easiest).